# What is the quickest way to get response code from server?

Tags: c#, http-response-codes

I have a WPF project where i need to as quickly as possible, check if a file exists on a server providing the url.

I have made a little method that uses WebRequest for this.

```
public bool URLExists(string url)
{
    bool result = true;
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Timeout = 1200;
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
    try
    {
        webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Although this is working, i think this can be done much faster.

I have read that you can use sockets, but i havent had any luck finding enough on it to actually understand and try, and i dont even know if it is a better option.

**My question is:** What is the quickest way to check if a file exist on a web server given the url to that file.

**The reason why i ask this question** is because the web server has a folder structure that looks like this: someserver.com/0/1/2.html, and i have three for loops set up like this:

```
for (int x = 2; x < 10; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < 80; y++)
   {
       for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
       {
           var url = string.Format("http://www.somserver.com/{0}/{1}/{2}.html", x, y, z);
           if (URLExists(url))
           {
               DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), filePath);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I know i want to wait and not fire of thousands of downloads at once, but this was to illustrate my purpose.

Comment: Instead of a request to check for the existence of a file, you could actually just try and download it and if it doesn't exist catch that error. That saves you a roundtrip.

Comment: I think it would make a lot of sense to check several URLs in parallel, although it would be nice (nice to the server) to limit the number of parallel requests. You could fire each request in its own Task and report back by calling some synchronized listener function. What happens then depends on what to do on success: Is one existing URL sufficient, or do you want to download all existing ones?

Comment: I tried to just fire of the download async but i couldnt find a way to check if the file exists. It would just download no mather what. I would want to download all existing files. Ill try a bit more setting this up differently. Thanks for the comments.